# Map COM object with automapper

Tags: automapper-3

I'm having an issue mapping from a COM object to an object. I believe the problem is that `GetType()` on the COM object returns `System.__ComObject`. How can I get around this?

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
Recipient -> RecipientModel
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient -> MyApp.Forms.Models.RecipientModel

Destination path:
RecipientModel

Source value:
System.__ComObject
```

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: I ended up just making my own mapping method that mapped it manually.

Comment: That is what I have done also as I do not completely understand the answer in the github thread. But the Example they are using in the thread is for outlook and they made it work. I am waiting for one of them to answer a question there for more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

This was brought up on the [AutoMapper Repo](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/768) and the solution is to map to only the COM class implementing the interface or just cast when mapping.

Comment: Do concrete classes even exist? In the Office stuff there is no class, everything is an interface.